# Bulk edit field overrides in all / specific library panels

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I monitor my docker containers using Grafana. However every time I add a new service, I have to edit all field overrides for CPU usage, RAM usage, network etc. in all my library panels, because the InfluxDB entries are rather long and not as concise as I want them to. Is there some way to override specific fields in every panel? Right now I change one panel and copy paste the resulting JSON for the overriding in all other panels manually, but this feels kinda wrong. Is there an easier way of doing things?